# How to print the address of struct variable in go

Tags: pointers, go, struct

I am new to go I want to print the address of struct variable in go 
here is my program

```
type Rect struct {
 width int
 name int 
}

func main() {
 r := Rect{4,6}
 p := &r
 p.width = 15

fmt.Println("-----",&p,r,p,&r)

}
```

output of this

```
  _____0x40c130 {15 6} &{15 6} &{15 6}
```

but i want to print the address of r variable as i know that '&' represents the address and '*' points the value of pointer location but here i am unable to print the address of r, I am using online editor of go-lang https://play.golang.org/

As well I want to store this address in some variable.

Comment: Have you tried the `%p` verb, with `fmt.Printf`? (https://play.golang.org/p/DpXgfJwsW63)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When you print values using [`fmt.Println()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println), the default format will be used. Quoting from package doc of [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/):

> The default format for %v is:
>
> ```
> bool:                    %t
> int, int8 etc.:          %d
> uint, uint8 etc.:        %d, %#x if printed with %#v
> float32, complex64, etc: %g
> string:                  %s
> chan:                    %p
> pointer:                 %p
> ```
>
> For compound objects, the elements are printed using these rules, recursively, laid out like this:
>
> ```
> struct:             {field0 field1 ...}
> array, slice:       [elem0 elem1 ...]
> maps:               map[key1:value1 key2:value2 ...]
> pointer to above:   &{}, &[], &map[]
> ```

The address of a struct value is the last line, so it is treated special and thus printed using the `&{}` syntax.

If you want to print its address, don't use the default format, but use a format string and specify you want the address (pointer) explicitly with the `%p` verb:

```
fmt.Printf("%p\n", &r)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jrSghe4UANv)):

```
0x414020
```